# difference between free-identifier=? and bound-identifier=?

Tags: scheme, racket, r6rs

Trying to understand free-identifier=? and bound-identifier=?. Can anyone give me equivalent code examples where using free-identifier=? would return true and using bound-identifier=? would return false.

Thanks

Comment: See [this email](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2011-April/045117.html) on the Racket mailing list, and the surrounding thread.

Comment: I understand what these functions should be used for, and I understand why they are defined the way they are (in terms of marks and substitutions). What I'm having trouble grasping is the circumstances in which they can give different results. A code example (even if fairly meaningless) would help with that.

Comment: Your best bet is to ask on the racket list.  Ryan will probably answer then.  (He's on SO too, but is more likely to miss it here, I'll ping him just in case.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
(define-syntax (compare-with-x stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ x-in)
     (with-syntax ([free=? (free-identifier=? #'x-in #'x)]
                   [bound=? (bound-identifier=? #'x-in #'x)])
       #'(list free=? bound=?))]))

(define-syntax go
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(go) (compare-with-x x)]))

(go) ;; => '(#t #f)
```

The `x` introduced by `go` has a mark from that expansion step on it, but the `x` in `compare-with-x` doesn't, so `bound-identifier=?` considers them different.

Here's another example:

```
(define-syntax (compare-xs stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ x1 x2)
     (with-syntax ([free=? (free-identifier=? #'x1 #'x2)]
                   [bound=? (bound-identifier=? #'x1 #'x2)])
       #'(list free=? bound=?))]))

(define-syntax go2
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(go2 x-in) (compare-xs x-in x)]))

(go2 x) ;; => '(#t #f)
```

Here `go2` also introduces an `x` with a mark, whereas the `x` given to `go2` as an argument does not have a mark. Same story.

Comment: Note that `(compare-with-x x)` also has the result `'(#t #f)` . The `go` macro is thus not needed for the first example.